# How does ことには lead to this meaning here?

Tags: meaning

I was watching *Steins;Gate 0* when I stumbled upon the following conversation:

So a little context is necessary to comprehend the situation. Two guys are talking about a recent event, where they were suddenly attacked during a friendly meetup in their "lab". As these two are talking about the event, one of them, to express their shock says this:

> 実はラボに戻ったら みんな待ってて―
> “ドッキリ大成功！ チャッチャラ～”みたいなことには

This supposedly means "I am half expecting everyone to jump out and say "Gotcha! You fell for it"
Trying to reverse engineer this sentence from the translation, there is nothing indicating "expecting", and there is a ことには that I can't really wrap my head around. My guess is that probably a verb would follow ことには if it weren't omitted like here, but what would work with ことには to imply this meaning?
Also, is this ことには kind of construct common to express disbelief?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not really about ことには, but rather you need to be able to see what is omitted. Here something like ならないだろうか is omitted after みたいなことには. (I don't know the anime, so may be missing something but should be fine.)

Literally, Xみたいなことにはならないだろうか translates to *I'm wondering, "won't a thing like X happen?"*. Hence the translation you give.

ことになる here means *It becomes/happens/come to be the case that...*.

---

For どっきり大成功, [this](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%89%E3%83%83%E3%82%AD%E3%83%AA) is relevant. Basically it is a disclosure that other people were just doing it (attack, in the particular case) as a surprise for fun.